# Why lubridate fails to parse some dates based on different Olson names for same time zone?

Tags: r, timezone, lubridate

I'm working with some data from the Canary Islands. The timezone in this Spanish region is officially WET/WEST. But this timezone also coincides with the British one for example - GMT/BST. Both change same hour and same day.

I tried to convert some characters (day-month-year) to dates using `lubridate` library and I am surprised that depending on the timezone I use, the function `dmy()` can fail to parse or not.

When I tried to parse directly all the date column using the timezone in `dmy()` `tz = "Atlantic/Canary"` - which is WET/WEST - it returns 9 failings to parse. This ones:

```
example = c("06/04/1980", "06/04/1980", "06/04/1980", "06/04/1980", "06/04/1980", 
"23/10/2008", "27/03/2017", "24/02/2011", "06/04/1980")
```

However, trying them alone, it successfully converts 3 / 9, unlike before.

```
> dmy(example, tz = "Atlantic/Canary")
[1] NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                "2008-10-23 WEST"
[7] "2017-03-27 WEST" "2011-02-24 WET"  NA               
Warning message:
 6 failed to parse.
```

And more surprisingly, If I set the timezone to British, it works perfectly. Also, the British one works perfectly for all the column at once:

```
> dmy(example, tz = "Europe/London")
[1] "1980-04-06 BST" "1980-04-06 BST" "1980-04-06 BST" "1980-04-06 BST" "1980-04-06 BST" "2008-10-23 BST" "2017-03-27 BST"
[8] "2011-02-24 GMT" "1980-04-06 BST"
```

I don't understand why the 3 cases are different. My original df is 10 million rows. However, even with the list of 9 dates, I don't know why the `dmy()` function output differs using one tz or another. If I were using hours, maybe it would be for some change, but that is not the case. Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Early April and late October sounds like a possible quirk with daylight savings time, but if it is just the date it doesn’t make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Early April' and 'Late October'? @Dave2e

Comment: If you give `dmy` a `tz` argument, it will return "a POSIXct with time zone attribute set to tz". As you can see from `as.POSIXct("1980-04-06", format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "Atlantic/Canary")`, that gives `NA` for this particular date. I think it has to do with the daylight savings time switch on that date.

Comment: I think this is where it happens: https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/master/tz/europe#L3660

Comment: Ohhh got it! Thank you. It is a strange behaviour though. Is there any way to set the date manually for that tz? @Bas

Comment: If you do not provide `dmy` with a time, it assumes it is midnight. However, the date time "1980-04-06 00:00:00" is ambiguous for Atlantic/Canary since it can correspond to two different times: before and after the DST switch. Why do you set the time zone if you are just using the date?

Comment: Compare `lubridate::dmy_h("06/04/1980 0", tz = "Atlantic/Canary")` (gives NA) with `lubridate::dmy_h("06/04/1980 1", tz = "Atlantic/Canary")` (gives "1980-04-06 01:00:00 WEST")

Comment: Actually, you are right, I don't need the tz. I'm just very used to doing it and then I discovered this strange behaviour. It makes all the sense if lubridate uses midnight as a reference. Thanks for your help @Bas